# check if the array can be split to subarrays which are equal in sum

Tags: c++

my problem i face is i cant run my code when i use cin>>arr
can i make it work with this code

```
  #include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

 int checkEqualSumUtil(int arr[1000], int N,
                int sm1, int sm2,
                int sm3, int j)
        {
     if (j == N)
        {
 if (sm1 == sm2 && sm2 == sm3)
 return 1;
    else
  return 0;
 }

    else
      {

int l = checkEqualSumUtil(arr, N,
                        sm1 + arr[j],
                        sm2, sm3, j + 1);


int m = checkEqualSumUtil(arr, N, sm1,
                        sm2 + arr[j],
                        sm3, j + 1);

int r = checkEqualSumUtil(arr, N, sm1, sm2,
                        sm3 + arr[j], j + 1);

return max(max(l, m), r);
        }
  }

      void checkEqualSum(int arr[], int N)
     {
      int sum1, sum2, sum3;

        sum1 = sum2 = sum3 = 0;

   if (checkEqualSumUtil(arr, N, sum1,
                    sum2, sum3, 0)== 1)
{
cout << "YES";
          }
       else
 {
    cout << "NO";
}
 }

  int main()
  {
    int n;
  cin>>n;
 int arr[n/2];
 for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
cin>>arr[i];


        int N = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0]);

     checkEqualSum(arr, N);
   return 0;
      }}
```

my code

i have edited my code the input is typed correctly

but it always outputs no

i dont know why any ideas??

also thank you for helping me all

i tried the input

3

1 1 1

it should print yes

put the output is no?

Comment: What is your specific technical question about C++, the programming language?

Comment: i input a test case like

5

1 2 3 1 4

it doesnt show no neither yes

but when i make it

arr[]={1,2,3,4,1}

it prints no

Comment: The C++ language does not have an overloaded `operator>>` for arrays.  You'll need some kind of loop.

Comment: i used it if u saw my code

Comment: Since you don't know the capacity of the array at compile time, use `std::vector<int>` and the `push_back` method.  Vectors are easier to pass and you can query them for their size.

Comment: Your value for `N` will always be 1000, because that's the size you declared for the array.  You have the variable `n` which tells how many valid entries are in the array.  So, my guess is that your functions are looping past the number of elements actually read.

Comment: still not working

Comment: "still not working" is not a C++ question. What is your technical question about C++?

Comment: i tried the input

3

1 1 1

it should print yes

put the output is no?

Answer (score 0):

Let's analyze your code in `main`:

```
int main()
{
    int arr[1000],n;
```

You have allocated an array, `arr`, that has a capacity of 1000 integers.
The array **is not initialized**.

An alternative declaration:

```
const unsigned int N = 1000;
int array[N];
```

The statement below reads the quantity of numbers to read into the array.

```
 cin>>n;
```

If the User or Operator enters a value larger than 1000, you will have undefined behavior.   Quantities less than 1000 are a waste of space.  Use `std::vector<int>` to contain elements when the capacity is not known during runtime.

```
for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
{
    cin>>arr[i];
}
```

Here you are calculating the **capacity** of the array.  The capacity was already declared as 1000.  See my suggestion about using N as the capacity.

```
int N = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0]);
```

The above line is not necessary.  Another option is to use a macro:

```
#define MAXIMUM_NUMBERS (1000)
```

The present form of the statement below, tells the function to use 1000 values, regardless of the quantity of numbers entered by the User.

```
checkEqualSum(arr, N);
```

For example, if I enter 5 numbers, the function call will translate to:

```
checkEqualSum(arr, 1000);
```

This because you initialized `N` to the capacity of the array.

Maybe you want to pass the quantity of numbers read into the array:

```
checkEqualSum(arr, n);
```

This is why variable names should differ in more than case.

This code is fine, telling the Operating System that your code run with no errors.

```
return 0;
}
```

Comment: I don't understand your comment.

Comment: i mean that everything is going great now buti still have a problem it always print no ..

Comment: That's a different issue than the one I answered.  Use a debugger, then post another question if necessary.  If this answer was helpful, please click on the check mark.

Comment: yeah i solved the first issue then another issue appeard